# Intent extras remain the same even when updated

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to pass a small bit of text between `Activity` instances using an `Intent` with extras.

This seems to work fine whenever I navigate between them using the back button or navigation in the action bar. However, if I visit the home screen and then relaunch the application, the extras passed are ignored; the second `Activity` seems to use the old `Intent`, rather than the new one.

The relevant code:

**Source activity**

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {
    protected void goToResults(String results) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, results);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**Destination activity**

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String results = extras.getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        // etc
    }
 }
```

I have tried a number of different things, including:

```
intent.setAction("action-" + UNIQUE_ID);
```

(as I understand that `Intent` instances are not compared by content of extras)

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

(I don't need `PendingIntent`, but thought this might force the `Intent` to update)

Any suggestions for how to force the `Intent` to show the changed data every time I make the transition from `ActivityA` -> `ActivityB`, regardless of whether I'm using the back button or a diversion to the home screen?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I remember running into this issue once, we solved it by either adding Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP to the intent you are sending:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

or by implementing the following method into the activity you're intent is launching:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(final Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        this.setIntent(intent);
}
```

I'm not 100% sure what fixed it again, believe it was adding the onNewIntent method.
Good luck and let us know.

Comment: Implementing `onNewIntent` did it. Thanks! (PS, anyone know why this is needed?)

Comment: I'm guessing it's because the activity is not actually relaunching because it was still alive. For me it would seem logical to replace the intent with the most recent one (That caused it to launch most recently). But I guess this way you can preserve the original intent and also check out the new ones.

Answer (score 3):

as @Lauw says :

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    this.setIntent(intent);
}
```

> this.setIntent(intent);

This line solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Also removing intent extras with `intent.removeExtra("key")` can help to update incoming new extras.

This approach helped for my case, when I was trying to launch app A from app B. Everything worked when app A wasn't opened, but when app A was already opened, I had to use the `removeExtra` method to get the updates.